# Run process after exiting putty

Tags: server, 16.04, putty

I'm running a compilation process that can take up to several days to complete on Ubuntu Server 16.04 .

I generally remote into this server using putty SSH, however I've run into a problem. Once I exit my putty session, the compilation terminates.

How can I make my process keep running after I exit Putty?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see that. Certainly a dupe, sorry!

Comment: Don't worry, happens to all of us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Background the process and use `nohup` to ignore `SIGHUP`:

   ```
   nohup make-foo arguments &
   ```
2. Run the compilation command in a terminal multiplexer, such as [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) or [GNU screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).  This allows both for the compilation to continue after you detach, and to be able to reattach to the same terminal at a later time to review output.